# how to make multiple windows forms fit at any resolution in winform application

Tags: vb.net, winforms

i am working on vb.net windows application..in master form i am calling two forms together..but while changing the screen resolution the forms are displaying not correctly...i want to display this form fit to screen always..in master form i am calling form like this:

```
 Dim frmVE As VisitorInfo
    Dim frmVX As VisitorExitsign

in ToolStripMenuItem_Click i have a code like this
frmVX = New VisitorExitsign
        frmVX.Location = New Point(781, 0)
        frmVX.MdiParent = Me
        frmVX.Show()

        frmVE = New VisitorInfo
        frmVE.Location = New Point(0, 0)
        frmVE.MdiParent = Me
        frmVE.Show()
```

my system resolution is 1366X768..but once i installed my application in client side..there having different resolution.that time forms not fit in the mdi parant form..
i want to fit my forms any resolution..how i can do that??
this is the proper image:[image]
this is the screen shot of client side ...there using systems having different resolution
[image]

Comment: knowing the profile of the typical user system is part of designing software.  start with a minimum resolution, then to support larger ones you can use a TableLayoutPanel to control where/how extra space is used on higher res screens

Comment: which property i have to change in TableLayoutPanel

Comment: the TLP controls how much space is allocated to the virtual rows and columns on the form.  You'd probably want to change the column width so that at larger res, both sections get more space.  Or you could fiddle with the design and use a TabControl where Tab1 is Entry and Tab2 is Exit.  Above or below the TabControl would be any controls common to both which seems to be few.

Comment: The screen is smaller. What did you want to happen to make it fit? Did you want everything to get smaller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your system should be designed to support minimum resolution lets say 1024*768, by doing this your application is supported to run on any larger (ONLY) resolutions.

Comment: You can solve it by dynamically drawing your UI , and i think this is extremely hard approach and the output is not guaranteed. 

my answer is that this problem cannot be solve, so that i moved to tabs by displaying each form in separate tab like chrome

Comment: so i have to give each forms in each tab??

Comment: this is the solution i came up with, display each form in separate tab,
this is one of the solutions i made 
http://sarisultan.com/#/portfolio/PMS.html

Comment: i have to change any property of the tab control?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean ?!

Comment: sir..i want to just keep my form inside the Tab?? you mean TableLayoutPanel right??

Comment: No, i mean tabControl , see this link
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/c-sharp-tabcontrol/

Comment: Yes you can open as much tabs as you want, Just imagine each form is a chrome browser tab